# Whats the best c++ stl container for fast lookup?

Tags: c++, stl

I search for a container which has a fast lookup time and I want to store  objects in it like the following

```
class Flow{
const int L3Outside;
const int L4Protocol;
const int L4Oustside;
const int L4Inside;
time_t inOut;
time_t outIn;
}
```

The container should only store unique elements BUT for the comparision whether two objects are equal only the constant variables must be compared.

Half of the time I try to insert an element if it isn't already in the container and half of the time I have to find and access an element if it is already contained in the container.

Also important their shouldn't be any collisions due to hashing or if they are collisions I must be able to insert both elements and also find only an element if their are equal not only their hashes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A 4-D matrix (that or loosen your restrictions)

Comment: How are you searching for you structure?  Are you comparing against all of the fields?

Comment: probably I don't have enough memory for a whole 4D matrix. In practice it would only be a sparse matrix

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to compare all constant variables of the class Flow. Or whats exactly your the question? sry

Comment: `unordered_set` with custom hash function and equality operator for your objects....

Comment: The title sasys "fast lookup" while the body says "half insertion, half lookup". This isn't strictly contradicting, but a sorted `std::vector` has very fast lookup in exchange for poor insertion performance. Is the title correct? Or does insertion performance matter?

Comment: @gha.st unordered_set was my first thougth, but I wasn't sure whether this works, becaues of the non-constant variables. thx I will try it.

Comment: @MSalters: let me say it that way. 50% time I just try to access an element, mostly it should already be in the container. In the other 50% I have to insert elements if they doesn't already exists, but most of the time they will already exists. So I think searching is more critical than inserting, because before I insert I have to search and check whether its already exists. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes, it makes it clear that you need both to be fast. For a sorted vector, search is O(log N) and insertion is O(N). So O (log N) + 1/2 O(N) = O(N) : insertion is more expensive than search for a sufficiently large vector (in practice I'd expect this to happen from N=20 or so)

Comment: @MSalters Thank you, that helps a lot. Do you also know Big-O for lookup and insertion of an unordered_set? Up to now, I couldn't find any :(

Comment: @Sebastian: O(1) for both, IIRC.

Comment: How many elements are you storing? A simple vector with linear search could be fine if it is small enough, where "small enough" can be determined through benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

**`std::multimap`**

**Lookup:** `O(log N)` plus linear if there are multiple elements for that specific key.

**Insertion:** `O(log N)`

Seems to be the most balanced speed for lookup and insertion with good handling of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

The std:: way to do this is as per the answer above - separate the immutable key from the mutable data, which is the purpose of a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

If you absolutely cannot do this for some legacy reason, you can use a `std::set` and provide a custom `less` functor. Or you could use a `std::unordered_set` in which case you'd need to provide a custom equality function object and a custom hash object.

Since c++11 however, be aware that the `std::set<>::iterator` type has const semantics (i.e. referent is not mutable) so you will need to force the issue with a const_cast:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <ctime>

struct compare_flow_less;

class Flow{
public:
    Flow(int l3o, int l4p, int l4o, int l4i, time_t io = 0, time_t oi = 0)
    : L3Outside { l3o }
    , L4Protocol { l4p }
    , L4Outside { l4o }
    , L4Inside { l4i }
    , inOut { io }
    , outIn { oi }
    {
    }    

    void set_times(time_t t1, time_t t2)
    {
        inOut = t1;
        outIn = t2;
    }

private:
    const int L3Outside;
    const int L4Protocol;
    const int L4Outside;
    const int L4Inside;
    time_t inOut;
    time_t outIn;

    friend compare_flow_less;
};

struct compare_flow_less
{
    bool operator()(const Flow&l, const Flow&r)
    {
        return l.L3Outside < r.L3Outside
        && l.L4Protocol < r.L4Protocol
        && l.L4Outside < r.L4Outside
        && l.L4Inside < r.L4Inside;
    }
};

using FlowSet = std::set<Flow, compare_flow_less>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FlowSet myflows;

    // to insert/overwrite a flow
    time_t t1 = time(nullptr);
    time_t t2 = t1 + 1;

    bool inserted = false;
    FlowSet::iterator insert_position;

    // try to insert a new one
    tie(insert_position, inserted) = myflows.emplace(1,2,3,4,t1,t2);

    // if insertion failed, one already exists so update it
    if (!inserted) {
        const_cast<Flow&>(*insert_position).set_times(t1, t2);
    }

   return 0;
}
```